# scapy on python 2.6 doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.6, scapy

I try to send network packet but when I import the scapy module this cause to terminated my app and I dont get any error or exceptions with this.

I wrote some little code for example:

```
print "Started"

import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

print "hi"
```

and my out put is :

```
Started
```

What can I do for fix this ?

Comment: What happens if you execute this code line by line in the interactive python interpreter? If you see an error message, make sure you add it to the question.

Comment: I tried this but i dont get error , but there i can send network packet

Comment: I check all the lines in my litle code and the problem in scapy . I dont get any errors. When I import scapy module its still not write any error and I also can send packet, Why is it work in idle ? and how can I fix this or at least get error . by the way in other computer this works fine.